# Error in FlutterSoundPlayer: The getter 'onPlayerStateChange' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-mediaplayer

```
"Error in Flutter when using flutter_sound: ^9.0.0 - The getter 'onPlayerStateChange' isn't defined for the type 'FlutterSoundPlayer'"
```

I am developing a Flutter application that utilizes th`e FlutterSound` library for audio playback. However, when trying to access the `onPlayerStateChange` event, I receive the following error:

```
`error: The getter 'onPlayerStateChange' isn't defined for the type 'FlutterSoundPlayer'`
```

My relevant code snippet is as follows:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sound/flutter_sound.dart';
import 'grelha_page.dart';
import 'splash_screen.dart';
import 'AudioVisualizer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late FlutterSoundPlayer _audioPlayer;
  bool isConnected = true;
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  bool isPlaying = false;
  late StreamSubscription<PlayStatus> _playerSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _audioPlayer = FlutterSoundPlayer();
    _checkConnectivity();


    _playerSubscription = _audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChange.listen((e) {
      if (e != null) {
        if (e.currentPosition == e.duration) {
          // Playback completed
          setState(() {
            isPlaying = false;
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void _playPause() {
    if (isPlaying) {
      _audioPlayer.stopPlayer();
    } else {
      _play();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _play() async {
    if (isConnected) {
      await _audioPlayer.startPlayer(
        fromURI: "URL_DO_SEU_STREAM",
        codec: Codec.pcm16WAV,
        whenFinished: () {
          setState(() {
            isPlaying = false;
          });
        },
      );
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = true;
      });
    } else {
      print("Sem conexão com a internet.");
    }
  }

  Future<void> _checkConnectivity() async {
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      setState(() {
        isConnected = false;
      });
    }
  }

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Radio Online'),
      ),
      body: _selectedIndex == 0
          ? Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            AudioVisualizer(player: _audioPlayer),
            Text(
              isConnected
                  ? isPlaying
                  ? 'A Ouvir'
                  : 'Pausado'
                  : 'Sem conexão com a internet.',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: isPlaying ? Colors.red : Colors.grey,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow),
                iconSize: 48.0,
                onPressed: () {
                  _playPause();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
          : GrelhaPage(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.radio),
            label: 'Rádio',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.grid_on),
            label: 'Grelha',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _playerSubscription.cancel();
    // Não há mais a necessidade de fechar a sessão de áudio
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class PlayStatus {
}
```

It seems there has been a change in the library or I am using the incorrect syntax. Can someone guide me on how to fix this issue and how to properly access the player state change event in the latest version of the library?

Previously, I used `onPlayerStateChanged`, but now it seems there has been a change to `onPlayerStateChange`. However, even after adjusting the code, I am still receiving this error.

Is there a specific change in version 9.0.0 of the flutter_sound library that I should be aware of? How can I fix this error and continue using player state functionalities?

Comment: can you first ensure you are using the latest version of this library and check the documentation for usage.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the documentation and the library version. I am using the latest version, but the error still persists.